# Trying to load a css stylesheet from a child template in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I have a parent template with this code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'base.css' %}"/>
    {% block additionalStyles %}{% endblock %}
</head>
```

and I have a child template with this code

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block additionalStyles %}<link rel="sytlesheet" href="{% static 'rants.css' %}"/>{% endblock %}
```

this doesn't seem to work and I don't get an error either. The base.css loads fine and when I inspect element on the webpage I can see `<link rel="sytlesheet" href="static/rants.css"/>` in the HTML code but it doesn't have any affect on any of the elements that it should. Is there a better way of doing this? and why is it not working?

Edit: It magically started working?? idk why or how, here is the new code if anyone has the same problem, in child:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Rants{% endblock %} 
{% block additionalStyles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'rants.css' %}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

in parent:

```
    {% load static %}
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}  </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'base.css' %}"/>
    {% block additionalStyles %} {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Did you add the `{% load static %}` tag?

Comment: yes i did in both the parent and the child template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to give the `<link>` it's own line

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Rants{% endblock %} 
{% block additionalStyles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'rants.css' %}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

Now works

Answer (score 2):

1. Kindly check the path to the folder that has the CSS file.
2. When everything seems to work correctly, remember to clear your browser cache or load the site/app in incognito mode(for Google Chrome users).
   In the child

   ```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block title %}Rants{% endblock %} 
    {% block additionalStyles %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'path_to_folder/rants.css' %}"/>
    {% endblock %}
   ```

In the parent

```
  {% load static %}
    <title>Parent site{% block title %}{% endblock %}  </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'path_to_folder/base.css' %}"/>
    {% block additionalStyles %} {% endblock %}
```